# How to use a confirmation dialog box in Odoo?

Tags: odoo

I'd like to get a value in a confirmation dialog bow in odoo.
I have a form with a select. When I choose a value in the select and click the save button, I have a diablog box with a message. In this message I'd like to get the selected value.
Any idea ?

```xml
<button string="save"
        icon="gtk-ok"
        type="object"
        name="update_year"
        confirm="The selected year is XXXX. Confirm ?"/>
```